# Email template fonts not rendering in gmail

Tags: magento2, email-templates, fonts

I want to know how we can use our custom fonts rendering inside email template. I searched a lot to this answer but didn't find how to do that.

So far I have already changed the content of `email-fonts.css` and `email-inline.css` and put my font-face declaration in the `email-fonts.css` file.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'museo_sans500';
    src: url('../fonts/museosans_500-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/museosans_500-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

  }
```

But I am only getting the font-family being applied to the element and actual font is not rendering in email template inside gmail. Font location is also local as in case of luma theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only webfonts that Gmail currently supports are Google Sans and Robot. Referenced here: https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts

Your problem with them rendering in the gmail client is because the fonts you are using are not either of the two Gmail supported webfonts.